# How far can the sharingan go?

Tags: naruto

The Sharingan makes the user able to follow the target better, which shortens the reaction time of the user. Does the Sharingan make your mind think faster as well?
If it doesn't, the users mind should not be able to keep up with what the Sharingan is able to see. If the mind becomes faster, then the user would become a super genius.

Or is there simply no logic at all?

Naruto has recently learned the flash ability from his father Minato. When someone uses flash are they teleporting or just moving really fast?

Additionally, could any form of the Sharingan "keep up" visually with the "flash ability" of either Naruto or Minato?

Comment: Please consider editing your question to ask 1 thing at a time (with the other beinging a seperate question) as the 2 question you ask don't seem to be related to one another

Comment: Sorry, but why is depending on what the answer is on question 2. I will have a follow up question..

Comment: btw, your profile pic is awesome. Code Geass 4 Life !!!

Comment: the stuff under the Sharingan are fine as "Does the Sharingan make your mind think faster as well?", "does it make you a genius" and "Or is there simply no logic at all?" are all related, I am talking about the Naruto Flash Ability which is asking if it's super speed or teleportation, this itself should be a separate question as the previous question is asking about the Sharingan

Comment: No,because if the answer would be that the flash ability is a speed thing instead of teleportation, then my next question would be if the Sharingan is able to keep up with it.

Comment: But you do not have that in the question, you first ask about the Sharingan then about Naruto's Flash Ability but there is nothing connecting the 2 and this follow up question does not exists

Comment: look now there are two answer for your question choosing correct answer will be difficult

Comment: I understand Memor-X, sorry for taking up your time.

Answer (score 3):

Sharingan by no means makes the bearer any smarter. Sharingan enables its bearer to:

1. See chakra of someone, but not the chakra points
2. See motions in greater detail making it feels like slow-motioned
3. Perform genjutsu better
4. Do sharingan specific jutsu, like Amaterasu, Izanagi, Izanami, etc.

The logic behind it is that normally humans don't use the maximal capacity of their brain, only about 10% if I'm not mistaken. In using the 2nd ability, Sharingan utilize more of the brain to do image processing, but not anything else. As for ability 1, 3 and 4, it's just that Sharingan is like a prerequisite to do so, just like a mere 160 cm basketball player would not be able to do slam dunk unless he have an ultra strong foot muscles. Sharingan is like that, only instead of foot, it's the eyes. Therefore, though Sharingan enables such feats I mentioned above, it doesn't make the user any smarter.

As for Naruto, as far as I know, Naruto is just moving very fast. His fast movement is different than that of Minato. Minato uses Space and Time Jutsu. That means Minato is not moving, he is teleporting. That's why he needs his kunai as marker.

Sharingan would not be able to keep up with it when he's on the teleportation, but when he shows up, it can.

Answer (score 0):

When Naruto learns the Flash ability just before he goes out to join the war, we see Naruto actually getting his foot stuck in some stone after failing at using the Flash ability. From this, we can tell that the Flash ability allows the user to move very fast, because it'd take a large amount of force for Naruto to hit the stone, crack it and get stuck in it. Where as based on concept, teleportation would not exert any sort of outward force, Naruto would shift positions in space, but his initial vectors would not change.

This moment is at 9min 39sec of episode 250 of Naruto Shippudan. Here Naruto get's stuck after hitting Kisame(Akatsuki Member) and Bee chases after Kisame as he tries to get away.

As we all know, the Sharingan further awakens based on the level of despair a user of the Sharingan goes through. Check the wiki for more info: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sharingan

> The Sharingan's power, because of its ties to the Curse of Hatred, is both a blessing and a curse. The moment that an Uchiha comes to know a powerful emotion towards someone, such as love and friendship, a stressful or emotional condition brought out from losing that precious person causes the brain to release a special form of chakra that affects the optic nerves while transforming the eyes into Sharingan.[26] After its initial activation, the Sharingan may be used freely, although it is possible for an Uchiha to lose memory of such an event and not reactivate it until through willpower years later.[27][28] When the Sharingan is first activated by a user, it has a different number of tomoe (巴) around the central pupil, varying between users.[29][27]
>
> The wielder of the Sharingan, through continued use and training, changes its form further, which involves the eye maturing fully until it has three tomoe. As the Sharingan develops, the user gains heightened abilities through the heightened ocular sense. For example, they can at least copy hand movements with one tomoe, predict a person's movement and copy techniques with two and completely use the Sharingan's abilities when it is fully matured. From what characters have noted, this dōjutsu apparently "glows" in the dark.[30][31] True to its name, the Sharingan and its derived forms have shown the ability to spin.[32] It is shown that when a person awakens their Mangekyō Sharingan without a fully matured Sharingan, their Sharingan will automatically mature while developing into a Mangekyō Sharingan.[33]

Comment: But if The flash ability = moving really fast, then why do minato need to put down a mark where he wants to go and why doesn´t Naruto need to?

Comment: This can be explained in a few ways. The mark can be used for prediction to result in less errors being made upon using the ability. If this is the case, it could explain why Naruto failed and Minato succeeded. That or Naruto can use the ability at a higher level than Minato, just that he hasn't mastered it yet, making him error prone.

Comment: @FatalSleep Pls try to backup your answers with site reference. I guess you are giving your own speculations in your previous comment.

Comment: I agree FatalSleep, I was thinking the same thing it´s just that I was wondering if they answerd this question in the series (Have I simply missed it or is there no sure answer?)

Answer (score 0):

[Flash ability](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique) is a teleportation. It's a space time technique something like Kamui. Naruto hasn't learned it so far. Naruto's speed,strength,skills are dramatically increased when he's in [Nine Tails Chakra Mode](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode).

Now his abilities are even increased with Sage's power.